# Tumblr template showed posts limit

Tags: html, post, limit, tumblr

i'm new in Tumblr and I need help.

```
{block:Posts}
   {block:HasTags}
      {block:Tags}
           <li><a class="meta-item tag-link" href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a></li>
      {/block:Tags}
   {/block:HasTags}
{/block:Posts}
```

This part show all hash tags but i need to show 10 tags only. how can I add some limit on `{block:Posts}`

Comment: What language is that in? Can you try using a loop? Is there not a setting somewhere that will set the tag limit?

Comment: I don't knwot what is the language, it's a tumblr language, the loop is {block:Posts} . no its only show in tumblr counter, but it can't help in this problem

Comment: Do you want a JS or CSS solution? Because that's the only way to get around this. There's no Tumblr code solution that I know of.

Comment: maybe js. but will be beter with tumblr code

Answer (score 2):

@Ally is correct. The `{block:Posts}` is used to render posts, in a loop. You can't use it to limit tags.

One way with CSS:

```
.tags li {
    display: none;
}
.tags li:nth-child( -n+10 ) {
    display: inline
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others have mentioned Tumblr does not appear to have a solution for this.

You can use a jquery solution below. Most tumblr themes include jquery, if yours doesn't it is relatively easy to install.

Here is a very straightforward jquery solution:

1: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/0ojymz2v/)

```
 $('.tag-link:gt(9)').hide();
```

It simply says, find every href which has a class of tag-link and hide anything above 10. This will probably only show the first 10 tag-links on the whole page, so you may need to modify this, at a guess it would look something like this:

```
 $('.post .tag-links:gt(9)').hide();
```

And here is a pure css solution (although it won't work in IE7 or less)

2: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/1tagc2gm/)

The css looks like this:

```
 li:nth-child(n+11) {
    display: none;   
 }
```

And that should work for every post on the page I believe.

Hopefully one of these solutions can help. If you need more info maybe we need to see your theme, or some of your code, but you can also play around with the jsfiddles.

Addendum: Have a look at this, this talks about the full tag list. 
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20616/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-tags-tumblr-can-remember